# I would like a complete list of features via email please

Tags: database

My problem is asking for a list of features through this difficult portal.

I hope the software isn't as user unfriendly as this portal.

Please send list of features to my work email address =   loris@outsidein.org

Answer (score 3):

You could also have a look at the User Guide to find out what CiviCRM can do. You can find the User Guide here: https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/

Also, it helps if you understand the CiviCRM is supported by a community. Almost all the people answering questions here do so in their own time without getting paid. They will do their best to help you. A command like: "Please send list of features to my work email address = loris@outsidein.org" sound just like that: a command.

Answer (score 2):

welcome to StackExchange. This forum is used typically for questions about using, administering, extending, and troubleshooting CiviCRM. That's not to say if you search the forum there haven't been questions asked and answered about what CiviCRM can do - but they are usually a little more narrow in scope.

For information on the features of CiviCRM, I'd suggest starting here: https://civicrm.org/explore-civicrm

If you are considering implementing the software and are looking for a more in-depth conversation about its capabilities you might consider reaching out to one of the CiviCRM partners (experts) listed here: https://civicrm.org/partners-contributors